# Need help with weird audio wire colors

Tags: audio, replacement

I would like to replace my broken earphone's 3.5mm audio jack. However, I am not able to indicate which wire is the right (red) and which is the left (green). I see the red and green wires but they are twisted with cooper. Please help me to identify each of them. I believe the gold one is the ground. Thank you.

[image: Color codes]

Comment: Can you input a low voltage (~100mVp) sine wave to the wire and listen for if there's sound on the left or right channel?

Comment: Hi Micheal. I'm really bad at this. How can I do that?

Comment: `red` does not necessarily mean `right`

Comment: the colours are a secret code known only to the manufacturer, what you need to do is figure out which wire goes to which metal part on the plug. the plugs are standardised

Comment: I once had a batch of 100 of these. Even within one batch there were three or four different colour codes.

Answer (score 1):

In the old days Windows PCs had a tool that allowed you to play a sound to one ear or the other, I suspect they still do.  I suggest you try connecting pairs of wires and see what works - you don’t need to make any assumptions about the colours.  If your headset doesn’t have a microphone then each ear will have 2 wires and you’ll probably end up connecting one from each ear to ground, which will be the main body of the connector.  If you have a microphone then the four wires will be left, right, ground and mic.  Use the same procedure to identify the connections that you need for left and right, then the remaining wire is the mic connection and that goes to the unused connection on the plug.  Don’t worry about mis-wiring when you’re testing, you won’t damage anything.